# Are there restrictions on Greyhound Australia's "hop on hop off" tickets?

Tags: tickets, australia, regulations, greyhound

Greyhound Australia offers [various "Hop on hop off" passes](http://www.greyhound.com.au/passes/hop-on-hop-off).

But searching around their website I can't seem to find the rules of these passes.

- Specifically can I only hop on and off a maximum number of times per pass?
- Do I *have to* book each "hop" in advance?

Answer (score 3):

From Greyhound Australia's web page:

> Remember, with our Hop On Hop Off passes, you can get on and off as
>   many times as you like, as long as you continue to travel in one
>   direction. Each pass is valid for 6 months from date of purchase and 3
>   months once travel commences, so you have loads of time to experience
>   the beauty of Australia!

I suppose this answers your questions?

Comment: +1.  There are also no limitations that I can see in the full T&C: http://www.greyhound.com.au/Clients/GreyhoundNew/Documents/PDFs/Greyhound_Ticketing_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf

Comment: Well, the terms and conditions actually specify that Greyhound Australia is only obliged to transport you if you have a reservation. This could be interpreted to mean that you are only allowed to use your Hop On Hop Off pass if there are free seats in the bus you intend to travel with.

Comment: Well, duh. What do you want them to do if there are no free seats, let you cling to the roof?

Comment: Well they could let you on without a booking if there is space and tell you "too bad" when there is not space but not require you to book. Or they could insist on booking in advance whether or not there is space at the last minute. I know some bus companies in Japan do it the last way.

Comment: @jpatokal Once long ago I sat in the steps to the door on a Greyhound bus, for a short trip (1 hour) on a completely full bus. The view was terrible though!

Comment: @jpatokal Other bus companies actually manage to offer all passengers a guaranteed seat, even without prior reservation. NOR-WAY Bussekspress is one example. They use stand-by coaches able to step in on short notice if the regular capacity is exceeded.